# Can you take a job to quit after 2 months?

Tags: new-job, job-hopping

I'm unemployed. The job I really want doesn't start interviews for 2 months. It has a high hourly pay, subsidized lunch, nurse on campus, concierge services, benefits, and a gym.  But I don't know if I can go without work that long.

I have a low offer of part time work, 25 hours at a retail store and a position as  manager at a restaurant I've been going for, that pays close but doesn't have the benefits.

Is it ok to take one of these jobs so that I am busy and have an income, while I wait for the interviews to start for my dream job? What might be the consequence of doing that?

Comment: Can you take a job with plans to leave after the first few paychecks? It's certainly possible. Is it polite to the employer? Emphatically not, unless everyone knows up front that it's a temporary position. Can you avoid going in under false pretenses? (We can't tell you which job to take, if either.) Remember too that you may not get the better job, or it may take months for them to get back to you; your short-term may be longer than expected.

Answer (score 9):

The new job:

- will start interviews in 2 months. If you were hired, you might not start work there until 3 months from now or even longer
- is not guaranteed to hire you. Presumably that money and those benefits will attract other candidates as well

The jobs you're considering:

- are traditionally high-turnover (restaurant, retail) and quite used to employees coming and going
- will keep you fed and occupied while you dream of your dream job

I would suggest taking whichever job you would prefer **long term** in case you do not get the dream job. In my experience, interviews for office jobs ask things like "where do you see yourself in 5 years?" and interviews for retail and restaurant jobs do not. However, **if you are asked** about your commitment to managing the restaurant or whether you would like to move from part time to full time at the retail store, tell the truth. If they care enough to ask, you owe them the truth.

Assuming they don't ask, or are ok when you say something like "I'm not sure, I like this work but am also interested in working at [dream job]", and you're hired at the stopgap choice, then commit to the job while you have it. Work towards the dream job while also being good at the job you take. If and when you get the dream job, give your notice at the stopgap job, apologize, and tell them you got an offer you couldn't refuse. They may be irritated but I doubt you'll have any long term consequences.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the "temporary" job might not be so temporary.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to take one of these jobs so that I am busy and have an
>   income, while I wait for the interviews to start for my dream job?

Certainly, as long as you tell the employer up front that you will be interviewing for a dream job you really want and expect to leave in about 2 months.

As long as both sides are in agreement, then everything is okay.

> What might be the consequence of doing that?

I assume you mean "What might be the consequences if they think I'm going to stick around, but I know I'm going to leave in 2 months and I do?"

You'll certainly lose any future references. The company that hires, trains and pays you only to lose you after 2 months will probably hate you. And if you have good personal ethics, you'll be violating them.

I think you already know this isn't a nice thing to do to an employer. You get to decide if you care or not.

Answer (score 0):

A life lesson that I've come across is:

> It's easier to look for a job while you have a job.

You are under less pressure to find a job and will have more mental confidence to negotiate. You can also be more picky with your opportunities. So yeah, I say if you have a high chance of getting a job now, go for it.

Now that isn't to say that you should take advantage of the part time job. You should still be grateful for it and give it your utmost professional attention and effort. Work as if it could potentially be a long term job. You never know what opportunities will flourish there either. I think you can still go for that dream job. I think everyone has that dream, so it's not a unique position to be in. It's just a part of life as you go through your career and make new experiences.

Just don't go into the temp job with an attitude like, "this is just temporary." Yes, the part time job will be good enough to help make ends meet. But, if you like the people there, it'll be a great opportunity to network. And it could also be a position you might be able to come back to if the dream job doesn't work out (ie not what you thought it was, any other unforeseen outcomes). Hopefully you'll have a great boss and great co-workers who will appreciate your work and the kind of person you are that puts forth the effort that any employer would be proud to have.

Good luck!